# Grails - Spring Security - redirect to specific page when remember_me cookie is present

Tags: grails, spring-security

When the user is "looged in"(remember_me cookie) and access the website I want to open a specific page  `Eg: /welcome.`

If the user is not "logged in" I want to open another page. `Eg: /`

Right now Im achieving this with `javascript` but Im sure there is a better solution. Through `UrlMappings.groovy` or `config.grooy` but didn't find any example.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
//redirect to welcome page if user is connected
var cookie_rm = $.cookie('sc_remember_me');
if(cookie_rm && window.location.pathname == "/"){
    window.location.href = "/welcome"
}
```

Thank you

Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can easily achieve this by using SecurityFilters.groovy. check the example given in [grails documentation.](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html)